# phoenix framework channel support json compression

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is it possible to compress json data in `Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket`?

Are phoenix channel android and iOS library support gzip compression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See on [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/). And there is a TODO article [Binary data over Phoenix sockets](https://nerds.stoiximan.gr/2016/11/23/binary-data-over-phoenix-sockets/). Possibly, you can use that solution, which supports a compression/decompression, too.